# Cloud Storage download URLs fail after three days, maybe due to Content-Type?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My Cloud Storage signed download URLs fail after three days. I think I've fixed the problem, so this question might be a solution to others. Ask me in three days whether this solution worked!

Here's the complete error message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.
</Message>
<StringToSign>
GET 1742169600 /languagetwo-cd94d.appspot.com/Audio%2FSpanish%2FLatin_America-Sofia-Female-IBM%2Fagua.mp3
</StringToSign>
</Error>
```

I googled the error message and saw some discussions that the problem is with `Content-Type`. I don't specify `Content-Type` in my code when I upload the files to Storage. When I set `contentType` in the code when uploading the download URLs fail immediately, with the same error message. That suggests that I'm on the right track.

```js
file.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-17-2025', 
  contentType: 'audio/mp3'
})
```

The expiration date in the download URLs is March 17, 2025, so that's not the problem.

Google's documentation on [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) says that the syntax is `Content_Type`. The IETF documentation on [content-type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) says that the syntax is `Content-Type`. I tried

```js
file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-17-2025',
    content_type: 'audio/mp3'
})
```

and my files download and play. I don't want to wait three days to see if they continue to work, so please let me know if there's something else I need to fix!

Just for grins I tried

```js
file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-17-2025',
    content-type: 'audio/mp3'
})
```

and `firebase deploy` wouldn't accept the code. The hyphen isn't allowed in keys.

Google's documentation on Signed URLs says

```
As needed. If you provide a content-type, the client (browser) must provide this HTTP header set to the same value.
```

`As needed` isn't the same as `Optional`.

My `.mp3` files and my `.webm` download URLs are failing, so it doesn't matter what the content of the files are.

Comment: It may be related to this: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/244#issuecomment-403601209

Comment: Could someone with 674 more points than I have mark this question as a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388061/getsignedurl-in-google-cloud-function-produces-link-that-works-for-several-day?

Answer (score 0):

Three days later, my download URLs are still working. It looks like

```js
file.getSignedUrl({
    action: 'read',
    expires: '03-17-2025',
    content_type: 'audio/mp3'
})
```

is the answer.

Comment: The problem is back. Today is March 27, and all download URLs from March 24 and earlier don't work.