# blob.generate_signed_url() cloud urls return SignatureDoesNotMatch after a few days occasionally

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

When I sign a google cloud storage url in App Engine, the url returns `SignatureDoesNotMatch` after a few days, but only sometimes.

Based on [Cloud Storage download URLs fail after three days, maybe due to Content-Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231676/cloud-storage-download-urls-fail-after-three-days-maybe-due-to-content-type), I thought adding content_type would fix it.

Here was my code:

```
credentials, _project_id = google.auth.default()
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(UPLOAD_BUCKET)
blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

signing_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
            source_credentials=credentials,
            target_principal=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            target_scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only',
            lifetime=2 )

url = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    expiration=timedelta(seconds=MEDIA_EXPIRATION), # 7 days is max
    method="GET",
    content_type=blob.content_type, # I think this is setting content_type=None, since blob.reload() is necessary to get a non-None value.
    credentials=signing_credentials
)
# note: I'm not sure if I could have just used credentials=credentials instead of the impersonated_credentials.
```

A small side note: blob.content_type was actually returning None. You have to do `blob.reload()` to get the content_type. But adding a content_type caused downloads to fail since browsers don't include content_type in the headers when asking for images.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated [getSignedURL() in Google Cloud Function produces link that works for several days, then returns "SignatureDoesNotMatch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388061/getsignedurl-in-google-cloud-function-produces-link-that-works-for-several-day) in a comment linking to https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/244 , a potential cause is **using the default app engine service account to sign cloud storage blobs**. The keys for the default service account get rotated every so often, and when that happens, all your signatures break.

To solve this, I created a dedicated service account with `Storage Object Viewer` privileges, downloaded the json key, put that in my project and used it directly.

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'my-service-account-json-key.json'
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only']
    credentials2 = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        path, scopes=SCOPES)

    url = blob.generate_signed_url(            
        version="v4",
        expiration=timedelta(seconds=MEDIA_EXPIRATION), # 7 days is max
        method="GET",            
        credentials=credentials2
    )
```

In my application, the security requirements are not high. Putting assets in a public bucket is plausible. The service account has very limited privileges, only `Storage Object Viewer`, so I'm not worried about including the private key in my repo. Better would be to put it in firestore or github secrets.

This particular issue is nefarious because your application can work for weeks or months if you get lucky on the timing of the default appengine service account key rotation. I will update this or remove if long-term testing reveals additional issues.

A lot of other answer talk about the expiration time. If a url expires, you get an expired error, not `SignatureDoesNotMatch`. The expiration time was never my issue, other than it being less likely to hit a default service account key rotation with longer times.